# canvas and stage losing global scope in easel.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

Here's the code. At the top, you can see that canvas and stage are declared as global variables. Then the initializeCanvas() function runs on page load and assigns those variables and loads a background image.

Strangely, though, stage and canvas end up undefined.

Why? And what can I do about it?

Roger

```
var canvas, stage

function initializeCanvas() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("starCanvas")
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    canvas.height = 720

    stage = new createjs.Stage("starCanvas")

    background = new createjs.Bitmap("background1.jpg");
    background.image.onload = handleBackgroundImage_Loaded
}

function handleBackgroundImage_Loaded(evt) {
    background.x = 0
    background.y = 0
    stage.addChildAt(background,0);
    stage.update()  
}   

alert(canvas)
alert(stage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `initializeCanvas`, an immediately invoked function. also, always use `console.log` to output an object for inspection.

```js
var canvas, stage;

(function initializeCanvas() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("starCanvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = 720;
    stage = new createjs.Stage("starCanvas");
    background = new createjs.Bitmap("background1.jpg");
    background.image.onload = handleBackgroundImage_Loaded;
})();

function handleBackgroundImage_Loaded(evt) {
    background.x = 0;
    background.y = 0;
    stage.addChildAt(background, 0);
    stage.update();
}
console.log(canvas);
console.log(stage);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="starCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This works if you strip out the canvas stuff... Otherwise, the code seems to run before the window.load event fires. 

At least stage ends up being defined, so it's definitely an improvement.

Comment: @user3055135 as you can clearly see in the given snippet, the code works perfectly. you just need to place your *script* before closing `body` tag

Comment: Okay, great... Thank you so much!

Comment: Would have been simplier to just call `initializeCanvas`  from the load event.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the function I guess.
Somewhere paste:

```
initializeCanvas();
```

Comment: No, I did that...I just didn't include that part:

<body style="background-color:#555;margin:0px;padding:0px" onload="initializeCanvas()">

Comment: @user3055135 This is the correct answer. The onload event will fire after the code you have has loaded and executed. The two lines with alert are run before the onload event and that is why the canvas and stage are undefined.